# How to use localization in conjunction with InAppSettingsKit? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, localization, settings.bundle

I'm making use of the `InAppSettingsKit` within my app, however I'm planning on adding localization to it. I was wondering if there's any support for localization of the settings when using the `InAppSettingsKit`.

I have had a look around online and haven't had much luck so far. I'm guessing that it will be something to do with `Settings.bundle` however I'm not sure what to do. Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have subfolders in my Settings.bundle, one per language, called en.lproj, de.lproj and so on. Each subfolder contains a Root.strings file which contains the localised strings. It's working for me so far.

So, the English Root.strings files has lines like:

```
// Root.strings (en)
"TITLE" = "My Localised Title"; // TITLE goes into a title field in your Root.plist
```

I forget whether it was possible to add the subfolders in XCode. In any case, you can definitely do that by manually editing the Settings.bundle contents in Finder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, Xcode's automatic localization support doesn't work for Settings.bundles. Apart from that it just works.